# Numpy equivalent of dot(A,B,3)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, dot-product

Say I have two 3 dimensional matrices, like so (taken from this matlab example http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html):

```
A = cat(3,[1 1;1 1],[2 3;4 5],[6 7;8 9])
B = cat(3,[2 2;2 2],[10 11;12 13],[14 15; 16 17])
```

If I want to take pairwise dot products along the third dimension, I could do so like this in matlab:

```
C = dot(A,B,3)
```

Which would give the result:

```
C =
  106   140
  178   220
```

What would be the equivalent operation in numpy, preferably a vectorized option, to avoid having to write a double for loop through the entire array. I can't seem to make sense of what `np.tensordot` or `np.inner` are supposed to do, but they might be options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using np.einsum:

```
In [9]: B = np.array([[[2, 2],[2, 2]],[[10, 11],[12, 13]],[[14, 15],[16, 17]]])

In [10]: A = np.array([[[1, 1],[1, 1]],[[2, 3],[4, 5]],[[6, 7],[8, 9]]]) 

In [11]: np.einsum('i...,i...',A,B)
Out[11]:
array([[106, 140],
       [178, 220]])
```

Or here's another fun one:

```
In [37]: from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

In [38]: inner1d(A,B)
Out[38]:
array([[106, 140],
       [178, 220]])
```

**Edit** in response to @flebool's comment, `inner1d` works for both (2,2,3) and (3,2,2) shaped arrays:

```
In [41]: A = dstack([[[1, 1],[1 ,1]],[[2 ,3],[4, 5]],[[6, 7],[8, 9]]])

In [42]: B = dstack([[[2, 2],[2, 2]],[[10, 11],[12, 13]],[[14, 15], [16, 17]]])

In [43]: inner1d(A,B)
Out[43]:
array([[106, 140],
       [178, 220]])
```

Comment: Notice that `A,B` do not have the right size here. In the Matlab code the arrays have shape `2,2,3`, while yours have shape `3,2,2`, requiring to change all the logic of the program

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution. Does it have any performance downsides compared to the einsum?

Comment: @Stankalank for the test array in your OP, `einsum` = 5.33 µs per loop, `inner1d` = 4.3 µs per loop. For a (2,2,10000) `einsum` = 42.6 µs per loop and `inner1d` = 41.6 µs per loop, although timings will vary on hardware and numpy version/compilation settings

Comment: Where's the documentation for `inner1d`?  Its `__doc__` is pretty skimpy.

Comment: @hpaulj I can't remember where I first stumbled across this method, but you can see form the import that it's not an obvious method to use. You can take a look at the source (C code) at: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/umath_tests.c.src

Answer (score 4):

```
In [169]:

A = np.dstack([[[1, 1],[1 ,1]],[[2 ,3],[4, 5]],[[6, 7],[8, 9]]])
B = np.dstack([[[2, 2],[2, 2]],[[10, 11],[12, 13]],[[14, 15], [16, 17]]])
c=np.tensordot(A, B.T,1)
np.vstack([np.diag(c[:,i,i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])]).T
Out[169]:
array([[106, 140],
       [178, 220]])
```

But surprisingly it is the slowest:

```
In [170]:

%%timeit
c=np.tensordot(A, B.T,1)
np.vstack([np.diag(c[:,i,i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])]).T
10000 loops, best of 3: 95.2 µs per loop
In [171]:

%timeit np.einsum('i...,i...',a,b)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.93 µs per loop
In [172]:

%timeit inner1d(A,B)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.51 µs per loop
```

Comment: What would be the generalized case for two `n x n` matrices?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how have you initialized `A,B`?

Comment: @flebool, pretty much as the other answer by joshAdel, see edit.

Comment: Notice that `A,B` do not have the right size here. In the Matlab code the arrays have shape `2,2,3`, while yours have shape `3,2,2`, requiring to change all the logic of the program.

Comment: @flebool, updated. Surprisingly, `tensordot` is the slowest. I actually avoided Einsterin summation assuming it will be slow.

Comment: I guess it is slower because of the for loop, and the call to `diag`. Clearly I was expecting `inner1d` to be faster, but it's not even documented, or at least I can't find the documentation for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
A = dstack([[[1, 1],[1 ,1]],[[2 ,3],[4, 5]],[[6, 7],[8, 9]]])
B = dstack([[[2, 2],[2, 2]],[[10, 11],[12, 13]],[[14, 15], [16, 17]]])

C = einsum('...k,...k',A,B)
```

Basically `dstack` concatenates along the third axis, ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)), and then you use the powerful einstein summation tool  `einsum` provided by numpy ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum))

Comment: so let's say I've already got my 2 3-d `n x n x k` arrays, all I need to do is `C = einsum('...k,...k',A,B)`? Would this be more efficient than a double for loop?

Comment: yes, it would be more efficient, and even more readable if you're used to Einstein summation.